# Colorized grep -- viewing the entire file with highlighted matches

Tags: bash, shell, colors, grep

I find `grep`'s `--color=always` flag to be tremendously useful. However, grep only prints lines with matches (unless you ask for context lines). Given that each line it prints has a match, the highlighting doesn't add as much capability as it could.

I'd really like to `cat` a file and see the entire file with the pattern matches highlighted.

Is there some way I can tell grep to print every line being read regardless of whether there's a match? I know I could write a script to run grep on every line of a file, but I was curious whether this was possible with standard `grep`.

Comment: if you want more than one color for more than one pattern (i.e. error, warning, info, etc messages), [use `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14691680/52074). the `sed` solution gets you multiple colors at the cost of added complexity (instead of about 30 characters you have about 60 characters).

Comment: With **sed** you can even **highlight + return exit code**, see example:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1200851/670392

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: With `sed` you could event send a **beep** on console terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69266748/1765658

Answer (score 1055, accepted):

Here are some ways to do it:

```
grep --color 'pattern\|$' file
grep --color -E 'pattern|$' file
egrep --color 'pattern|$' file
```

The `|` symbol is the OR operator. Either escape it using `\` or tell grep that the search text has to be interpreted as regular expressions by adding -E or using the `egrep` command instead of `grep`.

The search text "pattern|$" is actually a trick, it will match lines that have `pattern` OR lines that have an end. Because all lines have an end, all lines are matched, but the end of a line isn't actually any characters, so it won't be colored.

To also pass the colored parts through pipes, e.g. towards `less`, provide the `always` parameter to `--color`:

```
grep --color=always 'pattern\|$' file | less -r
grep --color=always -E 'pattern|$' file | less -r
egrep --color=always 'pattern|$' file | less -r
```

Comment: That |$ trick is neat! Well done, I'll have to remember that.

For those of you that aren't regular expression savvy, "pattern|$" will match lines that have the pattern you're searching for AND lines that have an end -- that is, all of them. Because the end of a line isn't actually any characters, the colorized portion of the output will just be your pattern.

Thanks Ryan!

Comment: You can also omit the "$": `egrep --color "pattern|" file` (credit http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398092/50979)

Comment: @Zack , the "|" operator is an OR operator, not an AND,

Comment: @JBoy, I was using 'AND' in the conventional English way rather than the boolean logic way. You're correct, it is indeed an 'or' operator -- it matches this and that. :P Good clarification.

Comment: It appears that the "$" is needed if matching more than a one pattern. `egrep --color "pattern1|pattern2|$"`. Otherwise the color highlighting does not happen.

Comment: You don't have to use the -E flag (extended regular expression) if you escape the '|', like so: `grep --color "pattern\|$" file`

Comment: "$" is required for a [regex-directed engine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html), like the `grep` on OS X Mountain Lion and Mavericks.

Comment: You don't even have to use the extended regex flag (`-e`), basic regex, which is the default, can match multiple patterns if the pipe is escaped. So this works for me: `grep 'pattern\|'`.

Comment: If you are going to pipe this into less and still want the output to be colored then you probably want to use grep --color=always and alias less='less -r'

Comment: @qwertyboy That is a feature of *GNU* `grep`. POSIX-compliant `grep` (*not*: `egrep`) supports only [*Basic* Regular Expressions (BREs)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) without `-E`, where alternation is not possible. (You should always use `egrep` instead of `grep -E`, to be sure you can use [*Extended* Regular Expressions (EREs)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04). `grep` implementations vary.)

Comment: @qwertyboy `-e` is different from `-E`. `-e` marks the following positional argument as a regular expression (so that it can begin with, e.g., `-`, and is still not considered an option); `-E` *additionally* enables ERE support. See the [POSIX `grep` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: Can we use different color for different matches -- egrep --color "pattern1|pattern2|$

Comment: Does this work well with "live" output? I'd like to colorize live logs from my test application by piping to a grep instance.

Comment: `grep -E` is preferred over `egrep` since many years back.  The answer seems to imply the opposite.

Comment: I would still use `--color=always` and not only `--color`, as the latter won't preserve the colorization when you pipe grep to another command, for example to `less -R`.

Comment: @13ren there are some variants of grep that optimize away "|", so 'pattern|$' is better (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13979036/939457).

Comment: Nice trick! Will this work when combined with other options, such as -F and -w? In my case no matches appear. I also prefer to have the non-matching lines highlighted as context. But, -C999 has problems too.

Comment: A question on a related topic:  how do I highlight the text not matching the pattern using `grep`?

Comment: the `-E` is a short for **`--extended-regexp `** if you, like me, like readability more than letter magic.

Answer (score 129):

Here's something along the same lines. Chances are, you'll be using less anyway, so try this:

```
less -p pattern file
```

It will highlight the pattern and jump to the first occurrence of it in the file.

You can jump to the next occurence with `n` and to the previous occurence with `p`. Quit with `q`.

Comment: Also works with piping (reading from stding) using `-`: `… | less -p pattern -`

Comment: @phk: You can even omit the dash.

Comment: Also, adding the `-i` option will make the match case insensitive as in `less -ip pattern file`.

Comment: ... and if piping in ANSI-colored input, provide `less` with the `-R` switch: `… | less -Rip introduction -`

Answer (score 51):

I'd like to recommend [ack -- better than grep, a power search tool for programmers](http://betterthangrep.com/).

```bash
$ ack --color --passthru --pager="${PAGER:-less -R}" pattern files
```

```
$ ack --color --passthru pattern files | less -R
```

```bash
$ export ACK_PAGER_COLOR="${PAGER:-less -R}"
$ ack --passthru pattern files
```

I love it because it defaults to recursive searching of directories (and does so much smarter than `grep -r`), supports full Perl regular expressions (rather than the POSIXish [`regex(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)), and has a much nicer context display when searching many files.

Comment: However, from time to time, it does not find what I want when I’m certain it must be there. `ack` is smart, but sometimes too smart, and it exluded the file type that the hit was in.

Comment: @MPi `ack -a` will search all file types, while still excluding `.git/` `.svn/` etc.

Comment: However, it is cool that `ack` does not search through my images, so `-a` does too much. I added `--type-set=freemarker=.ftl` to my `~/.ackrc`, to give one example.

Comment: With a few config tweaks, grep already does everything ack does, is faster, and never omits results like ack's whitelists sometimes do. Perhaps save your preferred grep settings in .bashrc. Mine reads: function grp() { GREP_OPTIONS="-rI --color --exclude-dir=\.git --exclude=tags" grep "$@"

Answer (score 32):

You can use my `highlight` script from https://github.com/kepkin/dev-shell-essentials

It's **better** than `grep` because you can highlight each match with its **own color**.

```
$ command_here | highlight green "input" | highlight red "output"
```

[image: Screen shot from Github project]

Comment: The question expressly asked for a solution using `grep`, which is a standard utility on machines running *nix.

Comment: This script is good, but not as good as `colout` mentioned in another answer.

Comment: @JonathanHartley And why is that so? I see no reason for it. Besides, this script uses a much simpler implementation than `colout`, which is good if you want to inspect what it does.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Yeah, fair enough. I should hold off on the judgement. colout is more thorough and powerful, but you are right that it is correspondingly more complex to use and reverse-engineer.

Comment: @JonathanHartley It makes sense that it is more powerful!

Comment: @HelloGoodbye, When choosing between a script utility and a hard-coded utility, I _always_ opt for the hard coded utility.  Just because you can see "what a script is doing" doesn't mean that something as fundamental as character escaping won't derail some small part of it.  I've bumped into all manner of trouble with various 3rd party bash/zsh that become laden with assumptions about just how POSIX they really think they are on this or that {uni,linu}x distro, and that is especially true in the era of mixed Unicode vs ASCII files.

Answer (score 23):

You can also create an alias. Add this function in your .bashrc (or .bash_profile on osx)

```
function grepe {
    grep --color -E "$1|$" $2
}
```

You can now use the alias like this: "`ifconfig | grepe inet`" or "`grepe css index.html`".

(PS: don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc` to reload bashrc on current session)

Comment: you could also use just use egrep if it's available on your system.

Comment: Piping the result of this to less loses the color information. How would you prevent that?

Comment: @Hoten use `--color=always` instead of `--color`

Comment: And, to make `less` interpret the color codes, use `less -R`.

Comment: The unquoted use of $2 is not blank safe. In a bash I'd rather do

    function grepe() {
      local pattern="$1"
      shift
      egrep --color "$pattern|^" "$@"
    }

Sorry for the formatting mess.

Answer (score 20):

Use `colout` program: http://nojhan.github.io/colout/

It is designed to add color highlights to a text stream. Given a regex and a color (e.g. "red"), it reproduces a text stream with matches highlighted. e.g:

```
# cat logfile but highlight instances of 'ERROR' in red
colout ERROR red <logfile
```

You can chain multiple invocations to add multiple different color highlights:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log | \
    colout ' 5\d\d ' red | \
    colout ' 4\d\d ' yellow | \
    colout ' 3\d\d ' cyan | \
    colout ' 2\d\d ' green
```

Or you can achieve the same thing by using a regex with N groups (parenthesised parts of the regex), followed by a comma separated list of N colors.

```
vagrant status | \
    colout \
        '\''(^.+  running)|(^.+suspended)|(^.+not running)'\'' \
        green,yellow,red
```

Comment: As noted elsewhere, the question expressly asked for a solution using grep, which is a standard utility on machines running *nix.

Comment: @Zack ok, sorry. Actually, if you expand the problem beyond `grep`, and it is already expanded in the answers, `colout` is the best solution for the problem you had, the best that I'm aware of. According to UNIX philosophy, programs should be written to do one thing well. For `grep` it is filtering text stream. For `colout` it is colorizing or highlighting text stream.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it can apply multiple different colored highlights, and `colout` is such a widely-useful tool. Learn it once, use it in many situations, rather than learning one tool to highlight logfiles, another to highlight test output, etc.

Answer (score 20):

The `-z` option for grep is also pretty slick!

```
cat file1 | grep --color -z "pattern"
```

Here's the documentation for the `-z` option:

> `-z`, `--null-data`
>
> Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline.  Like the `-Z` or `--null` option, this option can be used with commands like `sort ‐z` to process arbitrary  file names.

Comment: what does this doe?  -z  tells grep to use ASCII NUL as a line delimiter...

Comment: @vy32 -z essentially translates the entire file to a single line.  However, the replier presumed that grep also has the "--color" option set by default, which many people have configured in their alias for grep, but is not a default.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Works well when used in a pipe.

Comment: **_WARNING:_** @rickgn, This does _not_ pass through anything if none of the input lines have any match.  Test with `echo "hello\nthere" | grep -z x`.

Comment: @alife good point, and it's actually kind of cool, because what's the point of seeing any text if the pattern is not in the text? if long text, seeing no output could be faster that scanning the output just to find out there are no matches. :)

Comment: @Oliver, I would argue that to be a terrible violation of the "Principal of Least Astonishment" (AKA, "The Law of Least Surprise").  The question was how to cat out the file showing the matches as highlighted.  Not dump all the output if there are no matches.  For instance, with that technique it would be impossible to reliably daisy chain multiple greps for multiple potential matches.  So, no, I suspect most would not find that kind of anti-highlighter "actually kind of cool."

Comment: @alife good point about the chaining, but grep does not show any results when no pattern match so it is not least surprise. In fact it is the opposite, if there was output without pattern match, user would be confused.

Comment: (?)  @Oliver, we are _creating functionality_.  To show me the file (not show me nothing) with specified items highlighted. That it's using `grep` underneath (or awk, sed, perl, C, etc.) does not impact any Law of Least Surprise.  The goal as stated is _"viewing the entire file with highlighted matches"_.  No one would want to file to vanish suddenly given that criteria.  Perhaps if it were called _"viewing the entire file with highlighted matches but yielding nothing if there are no matches"_.  Anyway, be well; I'm tiring of this silly argument.

Answer (score 13):

As `grep -E '|pattern'` has already been suggested, just wanted to clarify that it's possible to highlight a whole line too.

For example, `tail -f somelog | grep --color -E '| \[2\].*'` (specifically, the part `-E '|`):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I use rcg from "Linux Server Hacks", O'Reilly.  It's perfect for what you want and can highlight multiple expressions each with different colours.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
#       regexp coloured glasses - from Linux Server Hacks from O'Reilly
#
#       eg .rcg "fatal" "BOLD . YELLOW . ON_WHITE"  /var/adm/messages
#
use strict;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

my %target = ( );

while (my $arg = shift) {
        my $clr = shift;

        if (($arg =~ /^-/) | !$clr) {
                print "Usage: rcg [regex] [color] [regex] [color] ...\n";
                exit(2);
        }

        #
        # Ugly, lazy, pathetic hack here. [Unquote]
        #
        $target{$arg} = eval($clr);

}

my $rst = RESET;

while(<>) {
        foreach my $x (keys(%target)) {
                s/($x)/$target{$x}$1$rst/g;
        }
        print
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I added this to my .bash_aliases:

```
highlight() {
  grep --color -E "$1|\$"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use ripgrep, aka rg: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep

rg --passthru...

Color is the default:

[image]

```
  rg -t tf -e  'key.*tfstate' -e dynamodb_table
       --passthru
       Print both matching and non-matching lines.

       Another way to achieve a similar effect is by modifying your pattern to
       match the empty string. 
       For example, if you are searching using rg foo then using 
       rg "^|foo" instead will emit every line in every file searched, but only
       occurrences of foo will be highlighted. 
       This flag enables the same behavior without needing to modify the pattern.
```

Sacrilege, granted, but grep has gotten complacent.

`brew/apt/rpm/whatever install ripgrep`

You'll never go back.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Searching in dependency tree is now easier.

`rg --passthru 'setuptools' <(poetry show --tree)`

Comment: Since we're allowing to go off-topic by suggesting different options to `grep`, may I introduce to you [`ugrep`](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep#performance-comparisons), which beats `ripgrep` in performance — and basically everything else out there — while, at the same time, adding lots of extra goodies. In my case, since `ugrep` includes the `--replace` option, I've since given up on `sed` and its quirky handling of regexps... and, unlike standard `grep`, `ugrep` is _much_ faster than `sed`.

Answer (score 5):

## The [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) way

### Preamble

This answer use [*`GNU sed`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/). This work with very old version of this tool (tested using 2012 version of *`sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`*, but this will work with older versions too.)

Unfortunately if on MacOS, [you may have to install them maybe by using `brew`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30003570/1765658)

### Power and flexibility of `sed` solution

As there is already a lot of different solution, but none did shown `sed` as solution,
and because `sed` is ***lighter and quicker*** than `grep`, I prefer to use `sed` for this kind of job:

```
sed 's/pattern/\o33[47;31;1m&\o033[0m/' file
```

This seems less intuitive.

- `s/pattern/replaced/` is `sed` replacement command to replace *`pattern`* by *`replaced`*.
- `\o33` is the `sed` syntax to generate the character *`octal 033`* -> `Escape`.
  (Some shells and editors also allow entering `<Ctrl>-<V>` followed by `<Esc>`, to type the character directly.)
- `Esc [ 47 ; 31 ; 1 m` is an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code): Background grey, foreground red and bold face.
- `&` will re-print the `pattern`.
- `Esc [ 0 m` returns the colors to default.

You could also highlight the entire line, but mark the `pattern` as red:

```
sed -E <file -e \
    's/^(.*)(pattern)(.*)/\o33[30;47m\1\o33[31;1m\2\o33[0;30;47m\3\o33[0m/'
```

### Dynamic `tail -f`, for real-time following logfiles

One of advantage of using `sed`: You could send a *alarm beep* on console, using *bell* [ascii character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `0x7`. I often use sed like:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/kern.log |
    sed -ue 's/[lL]ink .*\([uU]p\|[dD]own\).*/\o33[47;31;1m&\o33[0m\o7/'
```

Or, if using *`systemd`*:

```
sudo journalctl -akf |
    sed -ue 's/[lL]ink .*\([uU]p\|[dD]own\).*/\o33[47;31;1m&\o33[0m\o7/'
```

- `-u` stand for *unbuffered*. This ensure that line will be treated immediately.

So I will hear some beep **instantly**, when I connect or disconnect my ethernet cable.

Of course, instead of *`link up`* pattern, you could watch for `USB` in same file, or...

### Advantage of `sed`

For sample: You're Charlie, awaiting some mail from *Alice* or *Bob*, transiting by your ***mail server***:

So you have to search for *`from=.*\(alice\|bob\)@someserver.org`* in `/var/log/mail.log`.
As `sed` is a *language*, you could use many directives, for sample: avoiding `imap` and `pop` logs while watching for incoming request on some mail server:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log | sed -ue '
    /[[:space:]]\(imap\|pop\)d\[/d;
    /[^[:alnum:]]smtpd\[/{ 
        s/.*/\o33[30;47m&\o33[0m/;
        s/\(alice\|bob\)@someserver.org/\o33[31;1m\o7&\o33[30m/g;
    }
'
```

This will

- delete lines regarding *`imap`* or *`pop`* servers.
  ( lines containing `imapd[` or `popd[` ),
- highlight lines  regarding `smtp` server
  ( lines containing `smtpd[` ) and
- for lines containing `smtpd[`, highlight and beep when line containing `alice@someserver.org` or `bob@someserver.org` is found.
- Then print all *not deleted* lines (as `-n` switch was not used).

Answer (score 3):

To highlight patterns while viewing the whole file, [h](https://github.com/dczhu/mch) can do this.

Plus it uses different colors for different patterns.

```
cat FILE | h 'PAT1' 'PAT2' ...
```

You can also pipe the output of `h` to `less -R` for better reading.

To grep and use 1 color for each pattern, [cxpgrep](https://github.com/dczhu/cxpgrep) could be a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

another dirty way:

```
grep -A80 -B80 --color FIND_THIS IN_FILE
```

I did an

```
alias grepa='grep -A80 -B80 --color'
```

in bashrc.

Comment: this is problematic if the things you're looking for isn't there. Say due to an error, in which case you'll get nothing.

Comment: What is `-A80`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is one way,

```
wc -l filename
```

will give you the line count -- say NN, then you can do

```
grep -C NN --color=always filename
```

Comment: "-C 2147483647" if you don't want to wc first. Using a large number here doesn't appear to slow things down.

Comment: Where is the search string, and will this output anything if there are no matches as a highlighter is expected to?  For example, `echo "hello\nthere" | grep -C99 x` produces nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell script that uses Awk's gsub function to replace the text you're searching for with the proper escape sequence to display it in bright red:

```
#! /bin/bash
awk -vstr=$1 'BEGIN{repltext=sprintf("%c[1;31;40m&%c[0m", 0x1B,0x1B);}{gsub(str,repltext); print}' $2
```

Use it like so:

```
$ ./cgrep pattern [file]
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't have all the functionality of grep.

For more information , you can refer to an article "[So You Like Color](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8603)" in Linux Journal

Answer (score 1):

One other answer mentioned grep's -Cn switch which includes n lines of Context.  I sometimes do this with n=99 as a quick-and-dirty way of getting [at least] a screenfull of context when the egrep pattern seems too fiddly, or when I'm on a machine on which I've not installed rcg and/or ccze.

I recently discovered `ccze` which is a more powerful colorizer.  My only complaint is that it is screen-oriented (like `less`, which I never use for that reason) unless you specify the -A switch for "raw ANSI" output.

+1 for the `rcg` mention above.  It is still my favorite since it is so simple to customize in an alias.  Something like this is usually in my ~/.bashrc:

alias tailc='tail -f /my/app/log/file | rcg send "BOLD GREEN" receive "CYAN" error "RED"'

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) and do

```
ag <search> --passthrough
```

Answer (score 1):

I use following command for similar purpose:

`grep -C 100 searchtext file`

This will say grep to print 100 * 2 lines of context, before & after of the highlighted search text.

Answer (score 1):

It might seem like a dirty hack.

```
grep "^\|highlight1\|highlight2\|highlight3" filename
```

Which means - match the beginning of the line(^) or highlight1 or highlight2 or highlight3. As a result, you will get highlighted all highlight* pattern matches, even in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want highlight several patterns with different colors see [this](https://github.com/Curiosidad-Racional/Bash-Scripts/blob/master/colog) bash script.

Basic usage:

```
echo warn error debug info 10 nil | colog
```

You can change patterns and colors while running pressing one key and then enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [my approach](https://github.com/dimo414/util.gem/commit/0289f743), inspired by @kepkin's solution:

```
# Adds ANSI colors to matched terms, similar to grep --color but without
# filtering unmatched lines. Example:
#   noisy_command | highlight ERROR INFO
#
# Each argument is passed into sed as a matching pattern and matches are
# colored. Multiple arguments will use separate colors.
#
# Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/25357856
highlight() {
  # color cycles from 0-5, (shifted 31-36), i.e. r,g,y,b,m,c
  local color=0 patterns=()
  for term in "$@"; do
    patterns+=("$(printf 's|%s|\e[%sm\\0\e[0m|g' "${term//|/\\|}" "$(( color+31 ))")")
    color=$(( (color+1) % 6 ))
  done
  sed -f <(printf '%s\n' "${patterns[@]}")
}
```

This accepts multiple arguments (but doesn't let you customize the colors). Example:

```
$ noisy_command | highlight ERROR WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

`egrep 'pattern1|pattern2' FILE.txt | less -Sp 'pattern1|pattern2'`

This will give you a tabular output with highlighted pattern/s.