# Highlight text similar to grep, but don't filter out text

Tags: linux, grep, command-line-interface

When using grep, it will highlight any text in a line with a match to your regular expression.

What if I want this behaviour, but have grep print out all lines as well? I came up empty after a quick look through the grep man page.

Comment: Za? The `grep` I know just outputs the matching lines. What is this highlighting you speak of?

Comment: as a quick solution, use -A and -B, se to a high enough value you will see all lines. Proper solution is to probably use sed/perl/awk etc, to  add color-escape-codes around matching word only

Comment: @TomZych Not sure if you're being serious, but some distros don't have color enabled by default. Try the --color option

Answer (score 363, accepted):

Use ack. Check out its `--passthru` option here: [ack](https://metacpan.org/pod/ack). It has the added benefit of allowing full Perl regular expressions.

```bash
    $ ack --passthru 'pattern1' file_name

    $ command_here | ack --passthru 'pattern1'
```

You can also do it using grep like this:

```bash
    $ grep --color -E '^|pattern1|pattern2' file_name

    $ command_here | grep --color -E '^|pattern1|pattern2'
```

This will match all lines and highlight the patterns. The `^` matches every start of the line but won't get printed/highlighted since it's not a character.

(Note that most of the setups will use --color by default. You may not need that flag).

Comment: This doesn't work with all flavors of grep. Some `grep`s optimize the pattern for fastest match. Mac OS X Mountain Lion switched to a BSD-style grep for which this doesn't work. The optimized expression matches all lines, but nothing is highlighted.

Comment: As for @willkil, the grep version does not work for me. The only solution here was the **ack** approach.

Comment: The following worked for me: `grep --color -E '(^|pattern1|pattern2)' file name`. In some flavours of grep + other regexes do OR matching on patterns it needs to be inside brackets.

Comment: @uNople Adding the parens does not help on OSX Mountain Lion. I created a file that simply numbered lines 1..100000, then did `grep --color -E '(^|888|999)'`. The output was identical to the output from omitting the parens: Many lines were highlighted, but 99888 was _not_ highlighted.

Comment: My previous comment lead me to think of trying `grep --color -E '888|999|$'`: It works! The difference must be in using a [text- vs regex-directed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) regex engine.

Comment: The grep hack works for me and it's pretty. For those not so familiar with regexps, ^ will match any beginning of a line (that's why EVERYTHING gets printed) but, since it's not a visible character, it won't get highlighted. Then the first pipe (|) followed by your match is required. The second  pipe (and any other you may need) are optional. Also, works for commands, removing the `file name` -> ls | grep --color -E '^|pattern'

Comment: With OSX grep, ``grep --color -E 'pattern1|$'`` works

Comment: [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) has also got a `--passthru` option.

Comment: The `^|` is genius! It's even possible `grep -E '|pattern'`! (no `^`), `grep (GNU grep) 3.1, 2017`

Comment: [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) also has this option (it can be spelled `passthru` or `passthrough`).

Answer (score 128):

You can make sure that all lines match but there is nothing to highlight on irrelevant matches

```
egrep --color 'apple|' test.txt
```

**Notes:**

- `egrep` may be spelled also `grep -E`
- `--color` is usually default in most distributions
- some variants of grep will "optimize" the empty match, so you might want to use "apple|$" instead (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13979036/939457)

Comment: Like the @holygeek's answer, this doesn't work for all `grep`s. All lines match but nothing is highlighted.

Comment: You don't need the `-i` (case insensitive matches) there. Also, `--color` is the default in most of the setups, you may not need that. `grep  -E` works just like `egrep`. It will also work for command outputs like `ls | egrep 'pattern|'. The pipe can go after or before any pattern `|pattern'. You can use a set of patters adding more pipes `pattarn1|pattern2|`.

Comment: @willkil works for me with `grep (GNU grep) 3.4` on `Ubuntu 20.04.4`.

Comment: @Lenormju Yes, GNU `grep` also worked in 2012 when I commented. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13979036/1086034) for more details.

Answer (score 45):

**EDIT:**

This works with OS X Mountain Lion's grep:

```bash
    grep --color -E 'pattern1|pattern2|$'
```

This is better than `'^|pattern1|pattern2'` because the `^` part of the alternation matches at the beginning of the line whereas the `$` matches at the end of the line. Some [regular expression engines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) won't highlight `pattern1` or `pattern2` because `^` already matched and the engine is *eager*.

Something similar happens for `'pattern1|pattern2|'` because the regex engine notices the empty alternation at the end of the pattern string matches the beginning of the subject string.

```
[1]: http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html
```

**FIRST EDIT:**

I ended up using Perl:

```bash
    perl -pe 's:pattern:\033[31;1m$&\033[30;0m:g'
```

This assumes you have an ANSI-compatible terminal.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

If you're stuck with a strange `grep`, this might work:

```bash
    grep -E --color=always -A500 -B500 'pattern1|pattern2' | grep -v '^--'
```

Adjust the numbers to get all the lines you want.

The second `grep` just removes extraneous `--` lines inserted by the BSD-style `grep` on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, even when the contexts of consecutive matches overlap.

I thought GNU grep omitted the `--` lines when context overlaps, but it's been a while so maybe I remember wrong.

Comment: @sorin: Yes, but the question was also about highlighting matching lines while printing all lines, which simply isn't possible with all `grep`s. In particular, the selected answer and _your answer_ **don't work** on OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: +1 This doesn't deserve the downvotes, and at least it DOES work on OSX 10.7^

Comment: Works on Big Sur with two patterns (not three though) 
`grep --color -E '$|master|main|$'`

Comment: @rtc11 Strange. I have no problems with three, four, five alternates on Big Sur 11.3.1. Your example looks fine. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Why is this answer and similar ones getting upvotes? It does not answer the original question! The author of the question don't want to filter out text!!! This is an incorrect answer that got many upvotes, so frustrating so see this.

Comment: @AlexandreV. This doesn't filter. The regular expression matches all lines in all `grep`s I know, but only color highlights the desired text.

Answer (score 40):

You can use my **highlight** script from https://github.com/kepkin/dev-shell-essentials

It's **better** than grep cause you can highlight each match with it's **own color**.

```
$ command_here | highlight green "input" | highlight red "output"
```

[image]

Comment: This seems helpful, but it didn't work on my debian box even after changing the shebang at the top =(  Do I need more than just highlight.sh?

Comment: Works great! Love it.
Worth mentioning that it would be best to include the script into your ~/.bashrc, and remove the word "function". This way it works as a function from shell.

Comment: This also makes a perfect function for e.g. my .zshrc

Comment: Does not work on my machine: debian aarch64

Answer (score 28):

Since you want matches highlighted, this is probably for human consumption (as opposed to piping to another program for instance), so a nice solution would be to use:

```
less -p <your-pattern> <your-file>
```

And if you don't care about case sensitivity:

```
less -i -p <your-pattern> <your-file>
```

This also has the advantage of having pages, which is nice when having to go through a long output

Comment: `dosomestuff | less -p 'thingIwant'`

Comment: you can specify multiple patterns like this `less -p 'foo|bar'`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using only grep by:

1. reading the file line by line
2. matching a pattern in each line and highlighting the pattern by grep
3. if there is no match, echo the line as is

which gives you the following:

```bash
while read line ; do (echo $line | grep PATTERN) || echo $line  ; done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print "all" lines, there is a simple working solution:

```bash
grep "test" -A 9999999 -B 9999999
```

- A => After
- B => Before

Comment: This way the file get echoed completely every time grep has a match, which is very likely not what you want.

Comment: @sjas Er, isn't that *exactly* what OP wants?

Comment: @Kyle Strand, the OP wants to be able to print the entire file; with this solution, if a given file has ten matches for "test", this solution will print the file ten times, which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @user993865 Did you test it? That is not the case. (I.e., `grep` does *not* print any lines more than once.)

Comment: this will not work if no matches at all

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this because you want more context in your search, you can do this:

```
cat BIG_FILE.txt | less
```

Doing a search in `less` should highlight your search terms.

Or pipe the output to your favorite editor. [One example](http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/2008/03/reading-stdin.html):

```
cat BIG_FILE.txt | vim -
```

Then search/highlight/replace.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a pattern in a directory recursively, you can either first save it to file.

```
ls -1R ./ | list-of-files.txt
```

And then grep that, or pipe it to the grep search

```
ls -1R | grep --color -rE '[A-Z]|'
```

This will look of listing all files, but colour the ones with uppercase letters. If you remove the last | you will only see the matches.

I use this to find images named badly with upper case for example, but normal grep does not show the path for each file just once per directory so this way I can see context.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only part of this that actually answers the question is the end-of-pattern pipe character, which was already demonstrated in at least two other answers when you posted this.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and what you are really trying to do is to highlight occurrences of words as they appear in your shell. If so, you may be able to use your terminal emulator for this. For instance, in Konsole, start Find (ctrl+shift+F) and type your word. The word will then be highlighted whenever it occurs in new or existing output until you cancel the function.

Comment: Even if highlighting occurrences of words as they appear were the "real" need, this is not a generic solution. Even the find function for GNOME terminal (a similarly rich emulator) does not appear to behave this way (shifting focus back to the prompt immediately un-highlights the search pattern). And in any case, I'm not convinced that this is an XY problem.