# Grep output with multiple Colors?

Tags: bash, colors, sed, awk, grep

Is there an elegant method in bash for running `grep` against a text file with two or more patterns, and each pattern that matches is output in a different color?

So a line that matches on `MALE` and `AUGUST` would output `MALE` in blue and `AUGUST` in orange?
I am open to the use of `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and crayons or others.

Comment: `colout` may be helpful as colorizing solution: http://nojhan.github.io/colout/ `egrep 'MALE|AUGUST' file.txt | colout MALE blue | colout AUGUST yellow` or if you do not need to filter text stream, just highlight it, you can do it with `colout MALE blue <file.txt | colout AUGUST yellow`

Comment: Also check the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighted-matches

Comment: see cgrep in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104350/multicolored-grep and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104402/182661

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can cascade greps with different colors by specifying --color=always and using the regular expression 'foo|$' to pass all lines.

For example:

```
tail -f myfwlog | GREP_COLOR='01;36' egrep --color=always 'ssh|$' | GREP_COLOR='01;31' egrep -i --color=always 'drop|deny|$'
```

If you want the entire line to be highlighted, update your regular expression accordingly:

```
.... GREP_COLOR='01;31' egrep -i --color=always '^.*drop.*$|^.*deny.*$|$'
```

Comment: This does not work if the same values are defined in `GREP_COLORS` (note the trailing `S`) - try unsetting it before: `$ GREP_COLORS=` (`GREP_COLOR` is deprecated)

Comment: To update the entire line, modifying the regex is the wrong approach.  Instead, use `GREP_COLORS='sl=1;31' grep ...` and specify sl to color the whole line.

Comment: how to restrict the final output lines only to the line where a word is matched? Current command print all line, but color the word when found. I am looking for actual grep functionality in the output.

Comment: GREP_COLORS='sl=1;31'  highlights the WHOLE LINE.  Use mt=  instead

Comment: @mtk : a bit late, but the answers colorizes but shows all lines. if you don't want "non matching lines", take out the "|$" from the regexps  ($ matches all end of lines, hence all lines, and does not colorize anything there)

Comment: if you want only to hilight matching line, you can put an egrep before all:
tail -f myfwlog | egrep -i 'ssh|drop|deny' | GREP_COLOR='01;36' egrep --color=always 'ssh|$' | GREP_COLOR='01;31' egrep -i --color=always 'drop|deny|$'

Answer (score 38):

`grep` is a regular expression matcher, not a syntax highlighter :). You'll have to use multiple invocations of `grep`, using a different value of `GREP_COLOR` for each.

```
GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep foo file.txt | GREP_COLOR="1;36" grep bar
```

That would highlight "foo" and "bar" in different colors in lines that match both. I don't think there is a (simple) way to handle *all* occurrences of either pattern, short of merging the output stream of two independent calls:

```
{ GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep foo file.txt
  GREP_COLOR="1;36" grep bar file.txt
} | ...
```

which will obviously look different than if there were a way to assign a separate color to each regular expression.

---

You can use `awk` to substitute each match with itself wrapped in the correct control code.

```
 echo "foo bar" | awk '{ gsub("bar", "\033[1;33m&\033[0m");
                         gsub("foo", "\033[1;36m&\033[0m"); print }'
```

In each line, you globally replace anything matching the given regular expression with itself (`&`) wrapped in the ANSI escape sequences for desired color (which `grep --color` does for you). After processing all of the possible matches, you need to explicitly print the line.

Answer (score 20):

If you want something out of the box, you're probably looking for [hhighlighter](https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter#screenshots).

Here's an example:[image: JBoss output]

Take a look. It's incredibly useful for coloring words in different colors automatically. It's an impressive project that's built on top of [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/).

Comment: h highlighter is a small Bash function which automates building a pipeline of `ack` commands and works in the same manner as the other two `grep`-based answers.

Answer (score 11):

I had the need to highlight strings in text files, and did not find a way that suited my needs, so I wrote a simple C program to colorize strings matching regular expressions.

You can download the source code from GitHub :

```
git clone http://github.com/mbornet-hl/hl
```

then :

```
cd hl/cr; make
```

Here is the usage :

```
hl: version 1.21
Usage: hl [-h|-eidD][-E][-rgybmcwRGYBMCW] regexp ...
  -h : help
  -v : version
  -u : do not bufferize output on stdout
  -e : extended regular expressions
  -i : ignore case
  -E : print on stderr
  -r : red
  -g : green
  -y : yellow
  -b : blue
  -m : magenta
  -c : cyan
  -w : white
  -R : red     (reverse video)
  -G : green   (reverse video)
  -Y : yellow  (reverse video)
  -B : blue    (reverse video)
  -M : magenta (reverse video)
  -C : cyan    (reverse video)
  -W : white   (reverse video)
  -d : debug
  -D : display regular expressions
```

To colorize the word "red" in red, and the word "blue" in blue, you just have to type in the following command :

```
echo "red blue red blue" | hl -r red -b blue
```

and here is an example to highlight the output of the ifconfig command :

```
hl -ei -m '^(eth|(vir)?br|vnet)[0-9.]*:[0-9]+\>'             \
       -b '^(eth|(vir)?br|vnet)[0-9.]*\.[0-9]+\>'            \
       -c '([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}'                     \
       -g '\<UP\>|\<RUNNING\>|([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\>' \
       -y '^(eth|(vir)?br|vnet)[0-9.:]*\>'                   \
       -W '[0-9a-f]{4}::[0-9a-f]{4}\:[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{4}:[0-9a-f]{4}' \
       -r ' (errors|dropped|overruns):[^0][0-9]*'
```

The order in which you specify the colors is important : if a string matches several regular expressions, the 1st one as a higher priority than the 2nd one, the 2nd one as a higher priority than the 3rd one, and so on ...

Hope This Helps.

Comment: This has the best performance compared to the script based colouring solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try the wonderful rpen http://github.com/rtulke/rpen

```
require egrep or grep
```

Now you need to copy the *rpen.py* file into the right folder and give it appropraite rights

```
cp rpen.py /usr/local/bin/rpen
chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/rpen
```

then try

```
ps xau |rpen Ss "S\+" "\?\?"
```

Comment: On cygwin, i've found the rpen installation very easy. I couldn't get ack and h to work. Usage example: `$ cat ~/.bashrc | rpen alias export`

Answer (score 4):

So here's the version(s) using sed. Let's say you want the word "FAILED" to be colored red, that would be:

```
sed 's/\(ERROR\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/'
```

To have the whole line containing the word "FAILED" marked in red:

```
sed 's/\(.*ERROR.*\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/'
```

To have multiple words marked red:

```
sed 's/\(ERROR\|FAILED\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/'
```

To have multiple words and their wohle lines marked in red:

```
sed 's/\(.*FAILED.*\|.*ERROR.*\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/'
```

To have multiple colors (ERROR=red/FAILED=blue)

```
sed -e 's/\(ERROR\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(FAILED\)/\o033[34m\1\o033[39m/'
```

To use all this over ssh:

```
ssh user@host -t "tail -n 1024 -f /some/log/file | sed --unbuffered -e 's/\(.*ERROR.*\|.*FAILED.*\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/\(.*postfix.*\|.*dhcpd.*\)/\o033[32m\1\o033[39m/'"
```

And for not having to type this everytime, just declare it as a function in your bashrc.

For other colors look up ANSI codes.

Answer (score 3):

[cxpgrep](https://github.com/dczhu/cxpgrep) is right for this purpose - highlight patterns in different colors.

```
cxpgrep 'PAT1|PAT2|...' FILE_OR_DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `bline` ([Beautiful Line Output](https://github.com/shakibamoshiri/bline)) specifically designed for **complex** output and colorizing.

all lines, foreground red:

```
ls | bline -a red
```

all lines, foreground red, background green:

```
ls | bline -a red:green
```

all lines, foreground is default (NOTE.3), background is green:

```
ls | bline -a :green
```

add color-mode, odd lines (foreground) will be in light,italic,red

```
ls | bline -o light:red
```

add text-mode, as well

```
ls | bline -o light:italic:cross:red
```

combine options are okay:

```
ls | bline -a light:green -i red -I 7 -r yellow -R 5-10
```

using hex value, foreground in red

```
df | bline -H -a ff00ff
```

hex, foreground green, background red

```
df | bline -H -a 00ff00:ff0000
```

hex just background

```
df | bline -H -a :ffff00
```

look for string: 'sda' and make that/those line(s) green

```
lsblk | bline -m sda light:green
```

### some screenshots

1. 

[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

4.
[image]

5.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You can do it with grep ONLY! Tricks here are (1) you take /OR/ of the words you are searching; (2) you use -A and -B options with large enough numbers (larger then the line count of your file).

```
echo "you make it" > tmp
echo "you take it" >> tmp
echo "you cake it" >> tmp
echo "you bake it" >> tmp
echo "you wake it" >> tmp

GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep -P "(take|cake|bake)" --color=always tmp | GREP_COLOR='1;33' grep -P "(cake|bake)" --color=always -A10000 -B10000 | GREP_COLOR='1;34' grep -P "(bake)" --color=always -A10000 -B10000
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is below:

```
tailf logfile awk '/MALE/' {print "\033[34m" $0 "\033[39m"}  '/MALE/' {print "\033[33m" $0 "\033[39m"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've often needed this, and I tried several solutions, including [hhighlighter](https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter), which is mentioned in another answer here. But none of the solutions I tried worked reliably when using multiple patterns, overlapping matches, or in other corner cases like [single](https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter/issues/10) character [matches](https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter/issues/30).

So I decided to roll my own colorizer:

## [colorexp](https://github.com/EugenDueck/colorexp)

- it has a defined colorization logic: last match determines the color
- if capturing groups are used, only group contents will be colored

N.B. In contrast to grep, it prints all input lines, not just matching ones. So if you need filtering use grep, then pipe into colorexp.

### Examples

#### Basic Usage

- use the `-h`/`-H` options to only colorize the text, or only the background

[image: Basic Usage Examples]

#### Overlapping matches - last match wins

- all matches are colorized, and the color of the last match will be used

[image: Overlapping Matches Examples]

#### Capturing groups

- when using capturing groups, only the matched group contents will be colorized

##### Vary colors of groups in patterns

- when exactly one pattern is given, the default is to use different colors for each capturing group

  - in case of multiple patterns, the `-G` option can be used to enforce varying of the colors for each group

[image: Varying Group Colors Example]

##### Use the same color for all groups of a pattern

- when multiple patterns are given, the default is to use the same colors for all capturing groups of a pattern

  - in case of a single pattern, the `-g` option can be used to enforce use of a single color

[image: Same Group Colors Example]