# Bash: Selected Part in BOLD font in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, highlight

Is there any way to grep some text from large file and mark that in BOLD letters in Linux BASH shell ?
Like

> `Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`
>   `/dev/sda1              15G   11G  3.3G  76% /`
>   `tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm`
>   `/dev/sda3              51G   45G  3.8G  93% /home`
>   **`/dev/sdc1             917G  359G  512G  42% /data`**

I have above output and I want whenever system mails me about this df output the /data line should be in bold letters.

Comment: Do you want to see the complete text with the matched text highlighted? Please provide more details about your requirements. with GNU grep: `grep --color=auto`

Comment: `any way to grep some text from large file` -- yes.  `mark that in BOLD letters in Linux BASH shell` -- would depend upon your *terminal*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ANSI escape sequence you can do this (*though this is terminal dependent*):

```
echo -e "\033[1m$(grep '/data' file)\033[0m"
```

Will produce:

**`/dev/sdc1             917G  359G  512G  42% /data`**

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but i have some extended requirement in this regard,I want a whole line in BOLD if pattern is found.

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't really have bold (it does have bright which is effectively equivilent). You could use `sed` to insert the bash control codes, but if you are less concerned with the exact colour choice, you can use

`grep --color -E "text match pattern|" mylargefile`

To get grep to do the highlighting. (see [Colorized grep -- viewing the entire file with highlighted matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighting) for alternatives and discussion)