# Finding a string in docker logs of container

Tags: docker, grep

What is the best way to find a specific string in the logs of a docker container? Let's say I want to see all requests, that are made in the "nginx" docker image that came from a ip starting with "127."

grep wont work as expected on docker logs command:

```
docker logs nginx | grep "127."
```

It prints all logs, but does not filter the result!

Comment: The Question is: What is the best way to find a specific string in the logs of an docker container

Comment: Does `docker logs` send output to standard output? Because if it does then `grep` should work just fine. If not then it is a bit busted and you'll need to redirect standard error to standard output before filtering with `grep`.

Comment: check stderr et atdout, extract from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7440 `$ docker run -d --name foo busybox ls abcd
$ docker logs foo > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
$ cat stdout.log
$ cat stderr.log
ls: abcd: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Robse Sorry, your question was hard to get before you added that example. Looks like `docker logs` is hard-to-grep since it contains terminal control chars. I would grep trough the nginx log files.

Comment: wonder if you could do this with --follow so the grep keeps looping as containers are being initialized

Comment: More info on `docker logs` output to stdout and stderr: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41139

Answer (score 371, accepted):

this can happen if the container is logging to stderr, piping works only for stdout, so try:

```
docker logs nginx 2>&1 | grep "127."
```

- "**2>&1**" will tell the shell to redirect *stderr* to *stdout*
- "**|**" to give the "unified" output to grep using pipe

Comment: I wonder if the `docker logs` command itself prints to stderr instead of stdout.

Answer (score 39):

As vim fan I prefer to use `less` and search with `/` (or `?` for backwards search)

```
docker logs nginx 2>&1 | less
```

More about vim search [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-a-word-in-vim-or-vi-text-editor/)

Comment: Or `docker logs nginx |& less` for a few less characters :)

Answer (score 14):

```
docker logs <container_name> 2>&1 | grep <string>
```

Answer (score 14):

you can use these:

1. On all shells:

   ```bash
   docker logs nginx 2>&1 | grep "127."
   ```
2. Only on newer versions of bash works:

   ```bash
   docker logs nginx | &> grep "127"
   ```

---

##### What is this syntax?

- Standard input (`0`)
- Standard output (`1`)
- Standard error (`2`)

The `>` operator actually defaults to using `1` as the
file descriptor number, which is why we don't need
to specify `1>` to redirect standard output: (`date 1> now.txt` = `date > now.txt`)

###### all together

We can redirect multiple streams at once! In this example, we are
concatenating two files, redirecting standard output to a file called
insects.txt, and redirecting standard error to a file called error.txt.

```bash
cat bees.txt ants.txt > insects.txt 2> error.txt
```

###### getting fancy

If we wanted to redirect both standard output and
standard error to the same file, we could do `ls docs > output.txt 2> output.txt`

Or we could instead use `2>&1` which is a fancy syntax
for saying "redirect standard error to the same
location as standard output.

```bash
ls docs > output.txt 2>&1
```

###### getting fancier

Newer versions of bash also support a fancier syntax
for redirecting both standard output and standard
error to the same file: the `&>` notation

```bash
ls docs &> output.txt
```

Answer (score 12):

Additionally, I found it usefull to highlight some terms that I'm searching for in the logs. Especially on productive installations where a lot of log output is generated. In my case I want to highlight `COUNT(*)` statements. But with a simple grep I can't see the entire SQL statement since it's a multi line statement. This is possible [with `-E` switch and some regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981831/3276634):

For example, the following snippet search for all queries that contain  `COUNT(*)` as well as `count(*)`:

```
docker logs <containerName> -f | grep --line-buffered -i -E --color "select count\(\*\)|$"
```

Some explanation:

- `docker logs -f` tell docker to **f**ollow the logs, so the filter applys also to new entrys like when viewing it using `tail -f`
- greps `--line-buffered` switch flushes the output on every line, which is required to grep in real time when `docker logs -f` is used
- `-E` is an **e**xtended regex pattern, required to apply our pattern that allow us returning also the non matching results
- `--color` highlights the matched parts (seems the default behaviour on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but maybe not on other distributions, so I included it here to be safe)
- `*` is escaped to disable its [special glob functionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), where `(`, and `)` are masked to avoid their regex meaning as group, which is enabled by `-E` switch

If the container logs to stderr, you can pipe them [as Edoardo already wrote for a simple grep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207098/3276634):

```
docker logs <containerName> -f 2>&1 | grep --line-buffered -i -E --color "select count\(\*\)|$"
```

The `-f` switch could be omitted if no live grep is wanted. In both cases, you see the entire log buth with highlighted search term like this:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You could also use an [anonymous pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3657/188466):

```
docker logs nginx 2> >(grep '127.')
```

Comment: For some reason, this is the only answer that works for me. The others don't work, I can't lay my finger on it. It seems as if ```docker logs``` writes directly to the screen, bypassing STDOUT or STDERR.

Answer (score 7):

To follow up on the comments and clarify this for anyone else hitting this issue. Here is the simplest way I can see to search an nginx container log.

```
docker logs nginx > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
cat stdout.log | grep "127."
```

IMO its kinda messy because you need to create and delete these potentially very large files. Hopefully we'll get some tooling to make it a bit more convenient.

Comment: Unlikely - it doesn't look like `docker logs` will support separate stdout and stderr
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25683

Answer (score 6):

I generally use it with `-f` option as well, when I am debugging the issue

```sh
docker logs -f nginx 2>&1 | grep "127."
```

It will show us, what we are expecting in real-time.

To include timestamps, add -t

```sh
docker logs -ft nginx 2>&1 | grep "127."
```

Answer (score 4):

Run following command to extract container name for image nginx -

```
docker ps --filter ancestor=nginx
```

Copy container ID from last command & then extract log path for your container through below command

```
grep "127." `docker inspect --format={{.LogPath}} <ContainerName>`
```

Answer (score 1):

**First, use this command ( b1e3c456f07f is the container id ):**

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' b1e3c456f07f
```

**The result will be something like this:**

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/b1e3c456f07f2cb3ae79381ada33a034041a10f65174f52bc1792110b36fb767/b1e3c456f07f2cb3ae79381ada33a034041a10f65174f52bc1792110b36fb767-json.log
```

**Second, use this command ( you can use vim if you like ):**

```
nano /var/lib/docker/containers/b1e3c456f07f2cb3ae79381ada33a034041a10f65174f52bc1792110b36fb767/b1e3c456f07f2cb3ae79381ada33a034041a10f65174f52bc1792110b36fb767-json.log
```

Comment: shouldn’t it be `grep /var/lib/docker/… '127.'` instead of `nano`?

Comment: OC. You could even use MS Word or send it to your printer;) At least you should give advise how to search for the string, as this is the task to be solved

Answer (score 0):

The top-rated solution didn't work for me - *grep* printed this output and I couldn't properly find what I was searching for (I'm trying this with a custom docker container, not with *nginx*):

```
docker logs collector 2>&1 | grep "ERROR"
grep: (standard input): binary file matches
```

The solution for me was to use *grep -a 'pattern'*.

from grep's man page:

> -a, --text
> Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.

So this works properly for me:

```
docker logs collector | grep -a 'ERROR'
```