# Understanding docker logs

Tags: docker, logging, grep

We all know that we can search for a string in a log file and show the surroundings lines to the searched string:
*grep -AXX -BXX "searched" file.log*

Is possible do the same with the docker logs command?
I want to do is that if already know the string i'm searching happened around one hour ago,  using "since" with "after" and "before", get only the result and not all the log, for example something like this:
*docker logs --since=65m -A20 -B5 "searched string"  [ID]*

By now i copy all to a file, resulting sometimes a big file, and use a grep:
*docker logs --since=65m [ID] >> file.log

grep -AXX -BXX "searched" file.log*

Comment: You can just pipe the output from `docker logs` to `grep`: `docker logs --since=65m -A20 -B5 | grep "search string"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to documentation you cannot. However, you can grep with pipe

```
docker logs | grep "whatever"
```

[stackoverflow answer for grep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207098/2275775)

[docker documentation about logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

## Alternative for Development

However for development purposes I am using [datalust/seq](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/getting-started-with-docker) - just add the image to your docker-compose file and with small configuration (depends on language which you are using) redirect logs to nice searchable portal.

```yaml
# docker compose 
 seq:
    image: datalust/seq:latest 
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

The portal (under `http://localhost:8082` as I redirected default `80` port from Container to my `8082` port):
[image: seq image]

## Alternative for Production

For production purposes I would recommend to use something which is able to automatically collect logs from `stdout` and `stderr` like:

- [Logstack + Elastick Search](https://logz.io/blog/docker-logging/)
- [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)
- [New Relic logs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/logs/log-management/get-started/get-started-log-management)

To provide the highest standards to your app regarding logging and monitoring.

Answer (score 4):

`grep` will read from stdin when you don't give it a file. Specifically with `docker logs`, you'll want to merge stdout and stderr together using the `2>&1` notation. The result looks like:

```
 docker logs --since=65m [ID] 2>&1 | grep -A20 -B5 "searched string"
```

Comment: For a discussion on what's going on with this redirection, see [What does 2>&1 mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/what-does-21-mean)